# Shorthand with several if statements for renaming some values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, rename

I do have an array with objects. Some of the objects properties have to be renamed.

So I have a function which gives me the desired result and I surely know about switch cases but I guess there must be a way less laborius way to do so. So I'm wondering what's the correct way for a shorthand technique to rename some property values and keep the ones which don't have to be changed:

```
renameMinMaxActual(data) {
    const newArray = data.map(element => {
      if (element.key.includes('Min')) {
        element.key = element.key.replace('Min', '.min');
        return element;
      }
      if (element.key.includes('Max')) {
        element.key = element.key.replace('Max', '.max');
        return element;
      }
      if (element.key.includes('Actual')) {
        element.key = element.key.replace('Actual', '.actual');
        return element;
      } else {
        return element;
      }
    });
    console.log('newArray', newArray);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there are many ways to minimize the code - you mention 'shorthand' - here's one.  I'm interested to see what others offer.

With this approach, the set of keys to transform are defined in `keyTransforms`, which makes it quite easy to add new keys without changing the `transformKeys` function.

```js
// Define all keys to transform
const keyTransforms = {
  Min: '.min',
  Max: '.max',
  Actual: '.actual'
};

// transformKeys replaces all keys found in data according to keyTransforms object.
function transformKeys(data) {
  return data.map(element => {
  // replace if match found, otherwise no change.
    element.key = keyTransforms[element.key] || element.key;
    return element;
  });
}
// sample input data
const data = [{
  key: 'Min'
}, {
  key: 'Max'
}, {
  key: 'Actual'
}];

const result = transformKeys([...data]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two arrays

fromKeys(present keys) `fromKeys=['Min','Max','Actual'];`

and toKeys(modified keys) `toKeys=['.min','.max','.actual'];`

While iterating through entries if key is present in fromKeys get the index and use the same key to get the value from toKeys array and set it in the object to be returned in map() function.

```js
let data=[{Min:0,Max:1,Actual:5,type:"A"},{Min:0,Max:1,type:"B"},{Min:0,Max:1,type:"C"},{Min:0,Actual:5,type:"D"},{Max:1,Actual:5,type:"E"}];
let fromKeys=['Min','Max','Actual'];
let toKeys=['.min','.max','.actual'];
console.log(data.map(obj => {
        let newObj={};
        for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)){
             let index=fromKeys.indexOf(key);
             if(index!=-1)newObj[toKeys[index]]=value;
                 else newObj[key]=value; 
            }
        return newObj;
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```